# EC2 Network Error (tcp_error)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 micro instance which my Drupal Project is running on it. Sometimes on tasks which require a lot of PHP memory (e.g. When I run cron job, or clear drupal cache), page load lasts about 1.5-2 minutes and after that I get Network Error (tcp_error). Even typing on ssh Console slows down, sometimes I can't even type any command. After that I wait 15-20 minutes and it starts work fine.
PHP config:
PHP memory limit - 512 mb
page execution time - 300

instance is almost empty, I've only installed PHP, Apache, MySql server, Memchahed server and varnish.

What do I have to do to server worked stable?

//P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micro instance are not production ready and using them for anything other than lightweight workloads will end in unexpected behaviour as you push them beyond their indented use.

Increase your instance type and you should notice stable performance.